# Get checked list from thymeleaf to controller

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I want to do something very simple. Check some projects from a view and save the checked projects.

This is my view:

```
 <h1>Projects</h1>
            <table class="table table-striped" id="myTable">
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Summary</th>
                    <th>Check</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr th:each="p,iterationStatus : ${projects}">
                    <td th:text="${p.summary}"></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" th:value="${p}"/></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

In the checkbox I put the Project object as the value.

This is my partial controller method

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveChecked(@ModelAttribute("projects") Set<Project> projects){
    this.service.saveProjects(projects);

    return "home";
}
```

How can I pass the selected projects to the saveChecked method when I click on a save button? I already searched for an answer, but sadly never found one.
If  I understand it correctly @ModelAttribute("projects") will just return the whole list of projects and not only the selected ones.

Comment: What is the issue ? Are you getting the list in attribute?

Comment: @soorapadman I'm getting all the projects and only the checked ones. I basically want to check/uncheck projects and use this info in my controller

Comment: i understand your concern . if you are getting only checked ones is should be sette in check box `checked` right ?

Comment: @soorapadman Thats right

Comment: but instead you are setting `${p}` why is that?

Comment: @soorapadman I'm giving the value of checked the whole Project object, thats why p. Because i want to retrieve the checked project objects in my controller.